# Sorting ArrayList of arraylist<integer>

Tags: sorting, arraylist, integer

I have the following ArrayList>. I need to sort this ArrayList by the size of arrayLists inside it. How can this be done?

Thank you!

Comment: Check out this article: http://javatechig.com/java/core-java/how-to-sort-an-arraylist-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Write Comparator for and use sort method :-

```
  import java.util.*;  
 class ListComparator implements Comparator{  
public int Compare(Object o1,Object o2){  
ArrayList s1=(ArrayList)o1;  
ArrayList s2=(ArrayList)o2;  

if(s1.size()==s2.size())  
 return 0;  
  else if(s1.size()>s2.size())  
 return 1;  
 else  
 return -1;  
 }  
  }
```

Assuming you ArrayList is variable name myList.

```
  Collections.sort(myList, new ListComparator());
```

Refer this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/collections_sort_comparator.htm) to understand the concept in java

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
class Details  {

    public static void main(String args[]){
       ArrayList<Integer> listofcountries = new ArrayList<Integer>();
       listofcountries.add(89);
       listofcountries.add(5);
       listofcountries.add(3);
       listofcountries.add(9);

       /*Unsorted List*/
       System.out.println("Before Sorting:");
       for(int counter: listofcountries){
            System.out.println(counter);
        }

       /* Sort statement*/
       Collections.sort(listofcountries);

       /* Sorted List*/
       System.out.println("After Sorting:");
       for(int counter: listofcountries){
            System.out.println(counter);
        }
    }
}``
```

Use this code work. This code Work Correct

Comment: OP wants to short list of arraylist , not the list of integers. This code sorts on basis of value of element. However he wants to sort on basis of size of arraylist.